# Headphone icon on display of iphone

Tags: icon, headphones

Why is there a headphone icon next to the battery % on my iPhone display and how do I remove it ? I haven't seen that there before

Comment: It's really helpful if you include the model of your iPhone, which version of iOS you are running and even a screen capture.  Remember, we're not there to look over your shoulder.

Answer (score 2):

iOS 10.2 uses the headphone icon in the status bar (previously used for W1-enabled devices only, like the Beats Solo3) for every Bluetooth headphone.

When wireless headphones are connected, iOS 10.2 will show a headphone icon and battery level in the status bar.

I am still figuring out if you can turn if off. Will update my answer.

Comment: Don't think the headphone icon was _only_ used for W1 devices before... my cheapo Bluetooth running headphones have always shown up here.

Answer (score 0):

I plugged the headphones in and unplugged them several times and it worked! Icon disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 10.2 introduces a new headphone icon.  When any wireless Bluetooth headphones are connected to the device, they will show up in the form of a headphone icon in the status bar.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently this is the new Bluetooth icon on the iPhone

Comment: How does this differ or improve on older answers?

Answer (score -1):

It's the Bluetooth indicator. Changes to headphones when connected to an audio source.